# Keydown event is not working in IE and Chrome after dynamically clearing table row and adding new set of row to it !!! (Its working in Firefox)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, callback, keydown, dynamically-generated

I am trying to implement navigation in array through arrow keys. I got is working by following code.

```
"onLoad": function () {
        $('#tbl tbody').attr("tabindex", 1);
        $('#tbl tbody').keydown(function (event) {
            // Code for navigation to next or previous in table
        });
    },
```

Key down event is working fine on page load, just i need to click on table once and i am able to navigate through arrow key.
But I am facing problem after clearing table dynamically and adding new set of rows to it.At end of table i need to make call back to server which is clearing this table rows and adding new sets of row to is. now after that Keydown event is not working. I need to click on table again to navigate.
Note: This is happening only on IE and Crome. On firefox it is working fine and i am able to navigate on new set of data or rows.

Comment: Is there some problem in losing focus from table body after server call back?? If its is then how to verify and fix that.

Comment: Keydown is working fine after i am clicking on table. But i don't want to that, i want to retain table body focus after server call back complete so that keydown will work on new sets of row too.

Comment: Can you reset the focus when the table has been recreated ? Like so maybe : $('#yourtable').focus();

Comment: @jerome.s: No, I tried that too. I tried `$('#tbl body').focus(); $('#tbl body').trigger('click');` to mimic trigger on table body in java script. But this is also not working as i want.

Comment: @jerome.s: Its working now as u said. Previously i was doing that at wrong place. Now i am setting focus in Ajax call back function for table.

Answer (score 0):

Bind it with jQuery's `live` function.

```
$('#tbl tbody').live('keydown', function(e) {});
```

This applies the callback to elements created at run time as well.

**[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**

Comment: @Austine Brunkhorst: No, it not making any changes for me. Its is still giving me old behavior. I am able to get new set of row but i need to click on table to start navigation.

Comment: @Austine Brunkhorst: Keydown is working fine after i am clicking on table. But i don't want to that, i want to retain table body focus after server call back complete so that keydown will work on new sets of row too.

Answer (score 0):

It working for me now as suggested by jerome.s.

now what i am doing, i am setting focus when Ajax call complete and its call back function also done with its job to re-render table. when rendering part complete i have set focus to table body.

```
$('#tbl body').focus();
```

Thanks for your responses.